# Javascript: check multiple elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I have an array: `a=[10,11,12,13]`. How can check elements from a[0] to a[2] if they >0 in the shortest way and don't use for loop? Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: is the length of array is fix with more than 3 items? then you can just call it statically

Comment: Hi @ VLDCNDN, the length is fixed with 4 items

Comment: In that case `let isValid = a[0] > 0 && a[1] > 0 && a[2] > 0;`

Comment: What is meant by "check elements"? Do you want a list of all elements that meet the condition? Do you want a single (boolean) value that indicates whether or not all elements meet the condition? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `slice` the array to get the items within the specified indexes, then use `filter` to filter out the items that don't match the condition and check whether the length of the resulting array is the length of the range.

```js
const a = [10, 11, 12, 13]

const isValid = a.slice(0, 3).filter(e => e > 0).length == 3
//last index in slice is exclusive
console.log(isValid)
```